# Unable to sort arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, do-while

I am trying to print the unique elements in an array first followed by another iteration using do-while

```js
var arr1 = ['a1','a2','a3,' ,'b1', 'b2' , 'c1' , 'c2'];
var arr2 = [];
var userInput = 7;
do{
    for (var i =0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) == -1 ))
            {
                    arr2.push(arr1[i]);

                if (arr2.length == userInput)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

            }
}
}while (arr2.length == userInput);
console.log(arr2)
//output = ["a1", "a2", "a3,", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"]
//expected output = ["a1", "b1", "c1,", "a2", "b2", "c2", "a3"]
```

Comment: The thing is, you don't have any sorting condition, you are  just copying arrays.

Comment: Plus, "a3" < "b1" in javascript, so you are going to have to parse the strings and code a custom comparison to get your expected output.

Comment: Do you have to use while loop? There are better ways of doing it

Answer (score 1):

You could take the not number part an the number part as an array and sort

1. by the number part and
2. by the not number part.

This works as well for strings like `'foo42'`.

```js
var array = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = a.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/).slice(1),
        bb = b.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/).slice(1);

    return aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0]);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am trying to load balance the elements using the index itself.

Comment: what does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

The sort method specifies a function that defines the sort order. If you sort it based on the second character(the numeric value), the letters will be the second sorting criteria by default.

```
var arr1 = ['a1','a2','a3,' ,'b1', 'b2' , 'c1' , 'c2'];
var arr2 = [];

console.log(arr1.sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1]));
```

Comment: Where's `arr2` as output? Where's input variable affects on the resultant array?

Comment: @AksenP You don't necessarily need arr2, as the sort method changes the original array.

Comment: @msanford thanks for the comment, I have added explanation.

Comment: @Addis
Thank you for the response. do you see an issue trying to specify the unique element in the subsequent iteration using indexOf and simply pushing the element  into the new array?

Comment: @SaurabhKothari there is no wrong trying to push specific elements, it's just that you are not making any kind of sorting, you're just pushing all the elements into the second array.

Comment: @Addis thank you!
I am pushing it as long as the indexOf return -1 and arr2.length == userInput value
I am not sure why the If condition won't work!

Comment: @SaurabhKothari which line of code do you think will do the sorting? 
" indexOf return -1" -what this line of code does is that, it checks if an element is already pushed to arr2, if it doesn't yet it's index will be -1 so the element will be pushed. If the element already exists indexOf will return the actual index which is different from -1 so the if statement will not be executed.

Comment: So the if condition is working actually, it's just not doing any meaningful action. Besides if you had repetitions in your array, you wouldn't even get the original elements. But my question to you again is, where in your code do you think is sorting happening??

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
//original array
var arr = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3,', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

//original array, sorted
var sorted = arr.sort();

//set, to get only unique elements
var set = new Set(sorted);

//set expanded to get array, might use it without this
var result = [...set];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey, I converted the code block to a snippet so it's runnable. Interesting solution, I like `Set()`.